# Confusion over javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, function, webhooks, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to create a mockup mortgage function to learn API.ai webhooks, which is calling a function which calculates monthly mortgage payments. This for some reason is not sending anything back to API.ai, with the error message in JSON of "Webhook call failed. Error: 500 Internal Server Error". (I know the code is inefficient, but once it's working I'll clean it up)

It's called here:

```
var bankNames = assistant.getArgument('bankName');
        var arrayLength = bankNames.length;

        var avgYearPercent = getRandomDouble(2.5,4.2);
        var monthsLeft = 12;
        var loanAmount = getRandomInt(100000,300000);
        var output = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) 
        {   //calcMonthlyPayments(avgPercent, monthsLeft, loanAmount)
            var speech = bankNames[i] + " has an outstanding loan of " + loanAmount + " and your monthly payment is currently " + String(calcMonthlyPayments(avgPercent, monthsLeft, loanAmount));
            output = output.concat(speech);

            }
        output = '<speak>' + output + '</speak>';
        assistant.ask(output);
```

And this is the function:

```
function calcMonthlyPayments(avgYearPercent, monthsLeft, loanAmount)
{
    var i = (avgYearPercent/12)/100;
    var r = 1/(1+i);        
    var L = loanAmount;         
    var n = monthsLeft; 
    var P = (L*((1-r)/(r-(Math.pow(r, n+1))))).toFixed(2);

    return P;   
}
```

Comment: 500 indicates a server error.  Can you post your server logs or a trackback?  Can you setup an action map?  Or request handlers?  You may want to use this as a guide: https://github.com/actions-on-google/apiai-webhook-template-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js